# LINQ adding columns to base result set

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have three classes, `Code`,`CodeContact` and `Contact` which map to tables in a database.  In my code the classes have one static method which returns the data you'll find in the following SQL script

```
create table #Contacts
(ContactId int
,Name varchar(50)
,Phone varchar(50)
)
insert into #Contacts(ContactId,Name,Phone)
values   (1,'jon',111 )
        ,(2,'jim',222)
        ,(3,'james',333)
        ,(4,'john',444)
        ,(5,'tim',555)
        ,(6,'jane',666)
go
create table #ContactsCodes
(ContactId int
,CodeId int
)
insert into #ContactsCodes(ContactId,CodeId)
values   (1,1 )
        ,(1,2 )
        ,(1,3 )
        ,(1,4 )
        ,(2,2 )
        ,(2,3 )
        ,(3,1 )
        ,(3,4 )
        ,(4,1 )
        ,(4,5 )
create table #Codes
(CodeId int
,CodeText varchar(50)
)
insert into #Codes
values (1,'Code Red' )
      ,(2,'Code Blue' )
      ,(3,'Code Green' )
      ,(4,'Code Gray' )
      ,(5,'Code Black' )
      ,(6,'code clear' )
```

I'm looking for some advice on how to get LINQ code to acieve something like that following

```
declare @filter varchar(50) = (select 1)

        select   c.ContactId
                ,c.Name
                ,c.Phone
                ,case when varColumn.ContactId is null
                      then 'Not Present'
                      else 'Present' end as [Code Red]
                ,case when varColumn2.ContactId is null
                      then 'Not Present'
                      else 'Present' end as [Code Blue]
        from Contacts as c
        --****************end of 'cohort' base set of IDs
        --first item in filter list becomes a 
        --column on a DataTable
        left join 
        (
            select distinct cc.ContactId
            from Codes as codes
            left join ContactsCodes as cc
            on cc.CodeId = codes.CodeId
            where codes.CodeId =@filter
        ) as varColumn on varColumn.ContactId = c.ContactId
        --second item in filter becomes another column
        left join 
        (
            select distinct cc.ContactId
            from Codes as codes
            left join ContactsCodes as cc
            on cc.CodeId = codes.CodeId
            where codes.CodeId =@filter+1
        ) as varColumn2 on varColumn2.ContactId = c.ContactId
```

So let's say I have an IEnumerable with 1,2,3 in it.  I would like to iterate over the collection and left join to the `Contact.ContactId` column and simply give an indication if that particular CodeId was found in the `ContactsCodes` table.  Here's what the result looks like if you run the above SQL:

[image]

I will eventually need the tackd on column data to be pretty dynamic.  But for the time being, can anyone provide a direction to go?  I think the easiest choice might be to go the LINQ to SQL route and have the stuff inside the left join a stored procedure and call it X number of times for whatever's in the list, but I'm welcome to any suggestions.

Comment: Any reason you can't just call a stored procedure or view which handles the joins for you? The database will almost always be faster than client code.

Comment: @JDB because I will eventually need this to be far more dynamic that this example illustrates.  Table names and columns will be interchangeable eventually and I figure it'll be way easier to do that in LINQ vs writing a ton of dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hmm... sounds like you might need to rethink your approach to the problems, then. Dynamic queries like that are a pain, whether you're in SQL or LINQ. Even so... you may find this resource helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088